# Sub Form Field Frontend Editing Bug?

Tags: subform

I have been playing around with the new Subform field.  But it seems to be buggy in front end editing.  If I delete or move an item and click save, one of the items will be duplicated and no items removed.  The inserted html and interface all appear to be working, there are no js errors or anything like that - it's only on save that it puts all the items back in the orders of their data id with duplicates if i attempt reordering.  My twofold question is: has anyone else found this, and does the front end template matter?

My module param xml is like

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" >

            <field name="title" type="text" label="Title" size="50" />

            <field name="subform1" type="subform" formsource="modules/mod_basic_subforms/subforms/itemform.xml" layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable" multiple="true" min="1" max="20" label="Items" />    

        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

And my subform xml is like:

```
<form>
<fieldset name="theitem" label="Item">
    <field name="item_text" type="text" label="Name" size="50" />
    <field name="item_desc" type="textarea" label="Description" cols="50" rows="5" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I dug into the code and have submitted issue tracker with suggested solution here

https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/12006